# How to copy a report from one universe to another universe in BO?

Tags: business-objects

I created reports in one universe(ex: X universe)now i want to copy all the reports to another Universe (Ex:Y universe) in the same environment how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Web Intelligence or Desktop Intelligence reports?  For Web Intelligence reports, you can create a copy of the report and change the universe from X to Y.  In the process of changing the universe from X to Y, you will be prompted to remap your fields.  If all the fields have the same names and the names are universe between classes within the universe, then it will automatically map all the fields for you.  If any of the fields do not match or if any of the fields are mapped to the wrong field, then you can manually select the field in the new universe.